# list of items from a csv file not getting written into a dynamoDB table

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to seed a DynamoDB table named **weather** with a list of items from a file named **cities.csv**, but it seems like the write operation never completes and so the mapped async function never moves past the following statement

```
const response = await docClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
```

for each item in the list.  As a result, I am left with an empty, unseeded DynamoDB table.  Any ideas what is going on here?  I have been pulling my hair out over this.

I reproduced the code from my lambda function named **seedDynamo** below:

```
// es6 syntax for including modules
import * as fs from 'fs';

// es6 syntax for including modules
import {DynamoDB, PutItemCommand, DynamoDBClient} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

import { PutCommand, DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

export const handler = async(event, callback) => {

     console.log("entered handler function");

     const DDB = new DynamoDBClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
     const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(DDB);
     let params = {};

     const fileContents = fs.readFileSync("cities.csv", "utf8").split('\n').map(async (item_str) => {
          params.ReturnConsumedCapacity = "TOTAL";
          params.TableName = "weather";
          params.Item = {
              "sc": {
                  "S": item_str.split(",")[0]
              },
              "t": {
                  "N": String(item_str.split(",")[1])
              }
          };
 //         console.log(params);
          try {
              const response = await docClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
              console.log(response);
          } catch (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
          } finally {
              console.log("Success");
          }
      });
      
   setTimeout(function(){
       callback(null, "ok");
   }, 1000 * 10);
  
};
```

Here is a list of items **(cities.csv)** containing a subset of the records I used.

```
AGUADA,53
AKRON,22
ALTO,47
ANAHEIM,62
ANCHORAGE,57
ANN ARBOR,73
APPLE VALLEY,38
AUGUSTA,52
BARCELONETA,23
BERKELEY,60
```

Here is an execution log.

```
Test Event Name
seedDYnamoDB

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: 71627f6e-f384-4f6d-aa81-95588d90710d Version: $LATEST
2023-06-07T13:42:00.121Z    71627f6e-f384-4f6d-aa81-95588d90710d    INFO    entered handler function
END RequestId: 71627f6e-f384-4f6d-aa81-95588d90710d
REPORT RequestId: 71627f6e-f384-4f6d-aa81-95588d90710d  Duration: 1574.02 ms    Billed Duration: 1575 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 105 MB Init Duration: 506.99 ms

Request ID
71627f6e-f384-4f6d-aa81-95588d90710d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is this:

```
   params.Item = {
              "sc": {
                  "S": item_str.split(",")[0]
              },
              "t": {
                  "N": String(item_str.split(",")[1])
              }
          }
```

You are using the document client so it should be:

```
   params.Item = {
              "sc": item_str.split(",")[0],
              "t": parseInt(item_str.split(",")[1])
          }
```

You also have an async map funciton which you don't await, the code should be something like the followin (not tested):

```
     const fileContents = await Promise.all(fs.readFileSync("cities.csv", "utf8").split('\n').map(async (item_str) => {
          params.ReturnConsumedCapacity = "TOTAL";
          params.TableName = "weather";
          params.Item = {
              "sc": {
                  "S": item_str.split(",")[0]
              },
              "t": {
                  "N": String(item_str.split(",")[1])
              }
          };
 //         console.log(params);
          try {
              const response = await docClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
              console.log(response);
          } catch (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
          } finally {
              console.log("Success");
          }
          return response;
      }));
```

Comment: Ah. .  . this code works with **await** in front of the docClient.send function call.  I am getting successful responses with the 200 (OK) status code instead of <pending> Promises and an empty DynamoDB table.

Comment: Also, another issue was the **lambda default timeout** of 3 seconds was too short for the code to process the original cities.csv file with over 300 items in it, so after I increased it to greater than 12 seconds, the code worked perfectly.